# How to create Shell Script that is capable of allowing me to View, Modify and Append a text file that it creates

Tags: linux, bash

I need to create a shell script that :

- can Program a shell application to create a file.
- is able to view, modify and append file

Any help would be greatly appreciated. as i couldn't find any resources that help.

Comment: So, when you say journal file, you mean something like this : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_24.0.0/spss/base/syn_files_journal_file.html ? One that records events in a session?

Comment: I believe the implication was for the user to manually update the file

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? And specifically, what do you mean by modify? Do you mean a full editing capabilities (e.g. insert data into the middle of the file, replace existing text with new text, delete data from the middle of the file).
Anyway to achieve all of these things consider:  
View: cat mylogfile  or less mylogfile  or view mylogfile  
Append:  echo "new text" >> mylogfile  
edit: look at the sed command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script to get you started (untested):

```
file="$HOME/my_journal_$$"
printf "Enter what you want to do ([v]iew, [m]odify, or [a]ppend): "
read rsp
case $rsp in
    v* ) cat "$file" ;;
    m* ) vi "$file" ;;
    a* ) printf 'appended this @ %s\n' "$(date)" >> "$file" ;;
    * )  printf 'bad response, quitting\n' >&2 ;;
esac
```

You still have a lot of work to make it robust, flexible, use the same real text file between invocations, collect test to append, loop til you get a good response instead of existing, add a shebang, maybe use getopts for arg parsing, etc.. but it's a start. Good luck!

Comment: This is an awesome start, Thanks for your help!